# Reconfigure Macbook to use USB wifi card instead of PCI-e card

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, osx-mavericks

Is it possible to change a setting or configuration file to associate a USB wi-fi adapter with the built-in wifi tools (like the icon in the top bar) instead of the mPCI-e card?

Right now I am using the Realtek Wireless Network Utility to connect to networks, but it does not integrate well with other parts of the OS